# Get transaction details following an Google Universal Analytics event

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I track some clicks (on internal links) as events in Google Universal Analytics to measure how many transactions happen afterwards. Within a session a multiple of these events can occur. After the events, usually some other actions follow. Sometimes afterwards a transaction happens that includes one or more products.

I would now like to see the transaction turnover on product level grouped by event (e.g. action or label) - ideally even across sessions. In other words: I would like to know which products are bought after which links have been clicked. How can I achieve this? It would also be fine to "only" retrieve the transaction IDs thus that I would fetch the products of the transactions separately.

When I check the Google Universal Analytics interface from the events direction, I can see the total number of transactions grouped by event. But I cannot find a drill down into products or transaction IDs there?

I cannot use internal promotions as internal promotions allocate the conversion only to the last click but I would like to allocate it multiple times if multiple clicks happened before the transaction.

I was also thinking about using custom dimensions on user level instead and then storing the last x clicks comma separated in there, but the limit of 150 characters does not really give much flexibility there.

The raw tracking data would only be accessable with Google Universal Analytics 360, right? Or is there any other way to fetch the data via API or so?

Any other ideas are also highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Raw tracking data is not available in GA360, either - you can do an hit-level export to BigQuery, but that data is already sessionized (i.e. every hit will be attributed to a session-wide traffic source, custom dimensions will reflect the selected scope etc). Largely this seems to be a reporting task, I am not sure if this is really in scope for SO (which per the help center is supposed to deal with programming questions rather).

Comment: I just found my own post again as I am now having a similar case, where I am looking for similar data (product based revenue) following a site search: I would like to know which products are bought after visitors searched for specific terms... any ideas about this? I will start a bounty as I also was no successful in the Analytics help forums: https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/11411547?hl=it

Comment: Why don't you consider using google tag manager together with analytics ? You can send custom events.